# Яндекс карты: менять в зависимости от размеров экрана

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать яндекс карту, что бы менялась в зависимости от размеров экрана.? Я знаю, что это можно сделать, а вот как?? Может вы знаете:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может поможет, кому то...  нашла ответ... нужно просто задать ширину в % и высоту фиксированную(родительскому контейнеру карты), что бы можно было отсчитывать %.. А для того что бы изменялась высота нужно через js вычислять....

Answer (score 0):

Высоту указать фиксированную, а ширину "auto", если блок внутри которого карта расположена адаптивный, то и карта будет подстраиваться.